# Dos botones en FORM solo uno debe enviar

Tags: javascript, html5, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

He realizado un formulario con algunos **inputs**, entre ellos *text*, *checkbox* y *file*.

El problema lo presento con el ultimo tipo **(file)**. Necesito capturar varias fotografías desde la cámara de un dispositivo móvil. Para arreglármelas, inserte una tabla con 2 columnas. En la primera fila un *input* de tipo **file**, y un botón con la intención de crear una nueva fila e insertar un *input* de tipo **file**.

El botón realiza su función, añade el nuevo renglón con el *input* incrustado, pero también después de eso, realiza el envió del formulario. Busqué si tenia **DIV** o llaves sin cerrar pero en apariencia, no me imagino porque podría estar haciéndolo.

No son los únicos botones que tengo en formulario, tengo otro que me da acceso a la cámara con un script y funciona bien, adjunto el código de mi tabla y de la función de JS que uso:

```js
    function addrow()
{
    var mytable = document.getElementById("addevidence");
    var row = mytable.insertRow();
    var newcell1 = row.insertCell();
    var newcell2 = row.insertCell();
    newcell1.innerHTML = '<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">';
    newcell2.innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
                <label class="text-primary">Evidencias</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <table class="table" id ="addevidence"> 
                            <thead>
                                <tr></tr>
                                <tr></tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button id="addcamp" onclick="addrow()" class="btn">
                                        <span>
                                            <i class="fa-solid fa-file-image fa-2x"></i> addrow
                                        </span>
                                        </button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: no uses `<button>`. Cualquier elemento de ese tipo envía el formulario, puedes utilizar la etiqueta `<a>` y darle estilos para que parezca botón.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Respuesta rápida

Ponlo así (con su **type** correcto, sino el `<form>` se cree que es un submit):

```html
<button type="button" id="addcamp" onclick="addrow()" class="btn">
```

### Explicación

En tu pregunta parece funcionar bien, pero es porque no has encerrado el/los inputs entre `<form></form>`, que es como se puede reproducir el problema, como puedes ver en este snippet que si los lleva:

```js
function addrow() {
  var mytable = document.getElementById("addevidence");
  var row = mytable.insertRow();
  var newcell1 = row.insertCell();
  var newcell2 = row.insertCell();
  newcell1.innerHTML = '<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">';
  newcell2.innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <label class="text-primary">Evidencias</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <table class="table" id="addevidence">
        <thead>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
            </td>
            <td>
              <button id="addcamp" onclick="addrow()" class="btn">
                  <span>
                      <i class="fa-solid fa-file-image fa-2x"></i> addrow
                  </span>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

La solución es asombrosamente fácil, y consiste en agregar el tipo de botón que es con su **type=""**, que en este caso querrás que sea `type="button"` para que el navegador no se crea que es del otro tipo **submit**.

Aquí dejo otro snippet con el botón arreglado:

```js
function addrow() {
  var mytable = document.getElementById("addevidence");
  var row = mytable.insertRow();
  var newcell1 = row.insertCell();
  var newcell2 = row.insertCell();
  newcell1.innerHTML = '<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">';
  newcell2.innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <label class="text-primary">Evidencias</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <table class="table" id="addevidence">
        <thead>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" id="addcamp" onclick="addrow()" class="btn">
                  <span>
                      <i class="fa-solid fa-file-image fa-2x"></i> addrow
                  </span>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Lamentablemente muy obvio para no verlo, pero fue la solución

Comment: No te creas, no es tan obvio... si yo lo sabia es porque lo he visto en varias ocasiones en otras preguntas de distinto enunciado pero igual problema. Ojalá hubiera podido enviarte a alguna de ellas, pero no he sabido encontrarlas y he preferido darte una respuesta para guardármela de referencia para el siguiente :-)